# Spring MVC Handling dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I would like to know whats the best way to handle `org.springframework.dao.EmptyResultDataAccessException` in my application.

This error occurs when I try to select records from the database that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exceptions(data related) caught in `DAO layer` should not be passed in Service layer. You would handle all exceptions in dao layer and rethrow them with your custom exceptions like :

```
public class SomeDaoImpl implements SomeDaoInterface {

   public void someDaoMethod() throws Exception { 
      // code ...

      try {
         // code
      } catch(EmptyResultDataAccessException dataAccessException) {
         // rethrow exception
         throw new Exception(dataAccessException.toString()); // you can rethrow RuntimeException or Custom exceptions
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: i think you gave a spot on answer, thank you very much keep up the good work